# TF-IDF in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

I am computing the TF-IDF but for IDF part I faced some errors. Would you please guide me? What is the error

> TypeError: get expected at least 1 arguments, got 0

```
def computeIDF(docList):
    import math
    idfDict={}
    idfDict=dict.fromkeys(docList[0].get(),0)
    for doc in docList:
        for word, val in doc.items():
            if val > 0:
                idfDict[word]+=1
    for word, val in idfDict.items():
        idfDict[word]=math.log(3 / float(val))
    return idfDict

idfs1=computeIDF([DictA1])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in computeIDF
TypeError: get expected at least 1 arguments, got 0
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see by the traceback, the problem is in the line 4, which is

```
idfDict=dict.fromkeys(docList[0].get(),0)
```

Your `docList` variable is of type `dict`, and in [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) we see:

> get(key[, default])

The method expects you to specify a *key* to get. Actually, it's hard to suggest any default key because dictionaries don't have ordering.
You are trying to get a dictionary with similar keys as `docList[0]` which is the first document, but you don't need to. A common way to add a key `new_key` to a python dict would be just `dict[new_key] = value`:

```
>>> d = dict()
>>> d['foo'] = 0
>>> d
{'foo': 0}
```

But when you attempt to *increase* unexisting key, you get a `KeyError`. To avoid this, you should use `dict.get(new_key, 0)` to get 0 when there is no key yet.

```
>>> d['bar'] += 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'bar'
>>> d['bar'] = d.get('bar', 0) + 1
>>> d
{'foo': 0, 'bar': 1}
```

Another option is to catch a `KeyError` when you trying to increase the key.

So, the elegant solution would be to add

```
idfDict[word] = idfDict.get(word, 0) + 1
```

in the appropriate place and get rid of initialization line (line 4).

After I answered your question, I should mention some code style issues:

- try to switch to `snake_case`, if you use python frequently: `doc_list`;
- separate binary operators (e.g. `+`, `=`, ...) by spaces;
- put a space after comma: `d.get('foo',␣0)`;
- use `dict()` instead of `{}`: some people could have thought it's a set

Your code will become more readable by python community if you follow that rules. See [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) if you are interested in other issues.

Cheers!

Comment: @RezaCivil I appreciate. By the way, could you accept the answer if it answers the question clear enough?

Answer (score 0):

When you're using the method get from dictionary, you have to pass some argument( the index , or key value. ).

```
idfDict=dict.fromkeys(docList[0].get(),0)
```

Probably you meant to write without the get maybe? Without the structure of docList dictionary we can't help.

```
idfDict=dict.fromkeys(docList[0],0)
```